# How to show Admob or Facebook Native Ads In a RecyclerView but have no idea "A student of Programming"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob, facebook-audience-network

**I want to show Admob native ads or Facebook Native ads  in my app which is basically consist of grid and recycler view I tried a lot of tutorials but no results so far any help will be greatly appreciated**

**The Adapter shows video images in Recycler View or Grid view and i want to show native ads every 5th position**

**videoListAdapter.kt:**

```
package org.aitech.ai.gui.video

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.paging.PagedListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.aitech.libai.util.AndroidUtil
import org.aitech.medialibrary.Tools
import org.aitech.medialibrary.interfaces.Medialibrary
import org.aitech.medialibrary.interfaces.media.Folder
import org.aitech.medialibrary.interfaces.media.MediaWrapper
import org.aitech.medialibrary.interfaces.media.VideoGroup
import org.aitech.medialibrary.media.MediaLibraryItem
import org.aitech.resources.UPDATE_SEEN
import org.aitech.resources.UPDATE_SELECTION
import org.aitech.resources.UPDATE_THUMB
import org.aitech.resources.UPDATE_TIME
import org.aitech.tools.MultiSelectAdapter
import org.aitech.tools.MultiSelectHelper
import org.aitech.tools.safeOffer
import org.aitech.ai.BR
import org.aitech.ai.R
import org.aitech.ai.gui.helpers.*
import org.aitech.ai.util.generateResolutionClass
import org.aitech.ai.util.scope
import org.aitech.ai.viewmodels.mobile.VideoGroupingType

private const val TAG = "AI/VideoListAdapter"

class VideoListAdapter(private var isSeenMediaMarkerVisible: Boolean
) : PagedListAdapter<MediaLibraryItem, VideoListAdapter.ViewHolder>(VideoItemDiffCallback),
    MultiSelectAdapter<MediaLibraryItem>, IEventsSource<VideoAction> by EventsSource() {

var isListMode = false


var dataType = VideoGroupingType.NONE
 
private var gridCardWidth = 0
val showFilename = ObservableBoolean(false)

val multiSelectHelper = MultiSelectHelper(this, UPDATE_SELECTION)

private val thumbObs = Observer<MediaWrapper> { media ->
    val position = currentList?.snapshot()?.indexOf(media) ?: return@Observer
    (getItem(position) as? MediaWrapper)?.run {
        artworkURL = media.artworkURL
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }
}

init {
    Medialibrary.lastThumb.observeForever(thumbObs)

    mAdItems = ArrayList()
}

fun release() {
    Medialibrary.lastThumb.removeObserver(thumbObs)
}

val all: List<MediaLibraryItem>
    get() = currentList?.snapshot() ?: emptyList()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = parent.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater,
            if (!isListMode) R.layout.video_list_card else R.layout.video_grid_card, parent, false)
    if (!isListMode) {
        val params = binding.root.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
        params.width = gridCardWidth
        params.height = params.width * 10 / 16
        binding.root.layoutParams = params
    }
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position) ?: return
    holder.binding.setVariable(BR.scaleType, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
    fillView(holder, item)
    holder.binding.setVariable(BR.media, item)
    holder.selectView(multiSelectHelper.isSelected(position))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty())
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
    else {
        val media = getItem(position)
        for (data in payloads) {
            when (data as Int) {
                UPDATE_THUMB -> loadImage(holder.overlay, media)
                UPDATE_TIME, UPDATE_SEEN -> fillView(holder, media as MediaWrapper)
                UPDATE_SELECTION -> holder.selectView(multiSelectHelper.isSelected(position))
            }
        }
    }
  }

override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
    holder.binding.setVariable(BR.cover, UiTools.getDefaultVideoDrawable(holder.itemView.context))
    holder.job?.cancel()
    holder.job = null
   }

override fun getItem(position: Int) = if (isPositionValid(position)) super.getItem(position) else 
null

private fun isPositionValid(position: Int) =  position in 0 until itemCount

private fun fillView(holder: ViewHolder, item: MediaLibraryItem) {
    when (item) {
        is Folder -> holder.job = holder.itemView.scope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
            val count = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { item.mediaCount(Folder.TYPE_FOLDER_VIDEO) }
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.time, 
 holder.itemView.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.videos_quantity, count, count))
            holder.title.text = item.title
            if (!isListMode) holder.binding.setVariable(BR.resolution, null)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.seen, 0L)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.max, 0)
            holder.job = null
        }
        is VideoGroup -> holder.itemView.scope.launch {
            val count = item.mediaCount()
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.time, if (count < 2) null else 
 holder.itemView.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.videos_quantity, count, count))
            holder.title.text = item.title
            if (!isListMode) holder.binding.setVariable(BR.resolution, null)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.seen, 0L)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.max, 0)
        }
        is MediaWrapper -> {
            holder.title.text = if (showFilename.get()) item.fileName else item.title
            val text: String?
            val resolution = generateResolutionClass(item.width, item.height)
            var max = 0
            var progress = 0
            var seen = 0L

            text = if (item.type == MediaWrapper.TYPE_GROUP) {
                item.description
            } else {
                seen = if (isSeenMediaMarkerVisible) item.seen else 0L
                /* Time / Duration */
                if (item.length > 0) {
                    val lastTime = item.displayTime
                    if (lastTime > 0) {
                        max = (item.length / 1000).toInt()
                        progress = (lastTime / 1000).toInt()
                    }
                    if (isListMode && resolution !== null) {
                        "${Tools.millisToText(item.length)} | $resolution"
                    } else Tools.millisToText(item.length)
                } else null
            }
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.time, text)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.max, max)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.progress, progress)
            holder.binding.setVariable(BR.seen, seen)
            if (!isListMode) holder.binding.setVariable(BR.resolution, resolution)
        }
    }
}


fun setGridCardWidth(gridCardWidth: Int) {
    this.gridCardWidth = gridCardWidth
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int) = 0L

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
inner class ViewHolder(binding: ViewDataBinding) : SelectorViewHolder<ViewDataBinding>(binding) {
    val overlay: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ml_item_overlay)
    val title : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ml_item_title)
    var job: Job? = null

    init {
        binding.setVariable(BR.holder, this)
        binding.setVariable(BR.cover, UiTools.getDefaultVideoDrawable(itemView.context))
        if (AndroidUtil.isMarshMallowOrLater)
            itemView.setOnContextClickListener { v ->
                onMoreClick(v)
                true
            }
    }

    fun onImageClick(v: View) {
        val position = layoutPosition
        if (isPositionValid(position)) getItem(position)?.let { 
 eventsChannel.safeOffer(VideoImageClick(layoutPosition, it)) }
    }

    fun onClick(v: View) {
        val position = layoutPosition
        if (isPositionValid(position)) getItem(position)?.let { 
 eventsChannel.safeOffer(VideoClick(layoutPosition, it)) }
    }

    fun onMoreClick(v: View) {
        val position = layoutPosition
        if (isPositionValid(position)) getItem(position)?.let { 
eventsChannel.safeOffer(VideoCtxClick(layoutPosition, it)) }
    }

    fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
        val position = layoutPosition
        return isPositionValid(position) && getItem(position)?.let { 
eventsChannel.safeOffer(VideoLongClick(layoutPosition, it)) } == true
    }

    override fun selectView(selected: Boolean) {
        overlay.setImageResource(if (selected) R.drawable.ic_action_mode_select_1610 else if 
(isListMode) 0 else R.drawable.black_gradient)
        if (isListMode) overlay.visibility = if (selected) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        super.selectView(selected)
    }

    override fun isSelected() = multiSelectHelper.isSelected(layoutPosition)
}

private object VideoItemDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MediaLibraryItem>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MediaLibraryItem, newItem: MediaLibraryItem) = when {
        oldItem is MediaWrapper && newItem is MediaWrapper -> {
            oldItem === newItem || oldItem.type == newItem.type && oldItem.equals(newItem)
        }
        else -> oldItem === newItem || oldItem.itemType == newItem.itemType && 
oldItem.equals(newItem)
    }

    @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MediaLibraryItem, newItem: MediaLibraryItem): Boolean {
        return if (oldItem is MediaWrapper && newItem is MediaWrapper) {
            oldItem === newItem || (oldItem.displayTime == newItem.displayTime
                    && TextUtils.equals(oldItem.artworkMrl, newItem.artworkMrl)
                    && oldItem.seen == newItem.seen)
        } //else if (oldItem is FolderImpl && newItem is FolderImpl) return oldItem === newItem || 
(oldItem.title == newItem.title && oldItem.artworkMrl == newItem.artworkMrl)
        else oldItem.itemType == MediaLibraryItem.TYPE_FOLDER || oldItem.itemType == 
 MediaLibraryItem.TYPE_VIDEO_GROUP
    }

    override fun getChangePayload(oldItem: MediaLibraryItem, newItem: MediaLibraryItem) = when {
        (oldItem is MediaWrapper && newItem is MediaWrapper) && oldItem.displayTime != 
 newItem.displayTime -> UPDATE_TIME
        !TextUtils.equals(oldItem.artworkMrl, newItem.artworkMrl) -> UPDATE_THUMB
        else -> UPDATE_SEEN
    }
}

fun setSeenMediaMarkerVisible(seenMediaMarkerVisible: Boolean) {
    isSeenMediaMarkerVisible = seenMediaMarkerVisible
  }
 
 }

@BindingAdapter("time", "resolution")
fun setLayoutHeight(view: View, time: String, resolution: String) {
val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
layoutParams.height = if (TextUtils.isEmpty(time) && TextUtils.isEmpty(resolution))
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
else
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
view.layoutParams = layoutParams
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

read these documentation:

Admob
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start

facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/ad-formats/native/android